# First and second moments of truncated laplace distribution

Tags: distributions, moments, truncation, method-of-moments, laplace-distribution

I'm trying to estimate a distribution that looks like a truncated Laplace distribution. However, I can't find closed-form expressions of its first and second moments. I'm expecting closed-form ones as in truncated normal distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Have you guys found it before?

Comment: Truncated below, truncated above, or both? Are the bound(s) known? And if upper and lower, are they symmetrical? Moreover, what has your first line (about estimation) got to do with the question?

Comment: Let it be the truncated above (at $x = 1$) and below (at $x = -1$). @wolfies.

Comment: Have you tried by computing the integral? The moments are going to involve integrals of the form $\int_a^b x^p e^{-x} dx$, which have a closed form...

Comment: @lacerbi I've tried it which results in a quite long expression (about two rows of A4 paper). There's nothing I can subtract or eliminate from the expression. That's why I asked whether someone here has found a very nice expression as in the truncated normal distribution's case.

Comment: @wolfies I think it is in the following form, $\mu_t = \mu_{nt} + \delta(\mu_{nt})$. The subscript $t$ and $nt$ denote 'truncated' and 'non-truncated', respectively. And, $\delta(\mu_{nt})$ is an adjustment variable about $\mu_{nt}$. Btw, it can be asymmetric.

Comment: I think you should also specify the parameterisation you are using for the Laplace ... (standard, or 2 parameter, or other ...)

Comment: @wolfies it has both the location and scale parameters.

Comment: You should probably check your computations, I just computed the first moment and it's something along the lines of $\propto h (e^{(a - \mu)/h} (-a + h) - e^{(-b + \mu)/h} (b + h) + 2 \mu)$ where $a$ and $b$ are the two extremes, $\mu$ is the location and $h$ the scale parameter; and the proportionality constant will depend on the integral of the zeroth moment (not particularly nice but not two rows of A4 paper).

Comment: @wolfies I'm sorry to leave it out. Yes the $\mu$ is within -1 and 1, and so is the $\mu^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:  $X \sim \text{Laplace}(\mu, \sigma)$ where $-1 < \mu <1$, with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/Laplacepdf2param.png))</sub>

Then, the (doubly truncated) conditional density, truncated above at 1, and below at -1, is:

$$g(x) \; = \; f(x \;\big|-1<X< 1) \; = \; \frac{f(x)}{P(-1<X<1)} $$

Here, $P(-1<X<1)$ is given by:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/laplaceprobminus11.png))</sub>

Then, the doubly truncated pdf $g(x)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/doublytruncatedLaplace.png))</sub>

Here is a plot of the doubly truncated Laplace pdf $g(x)$, given some different paramater combinations:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/plotdoublytruncatedLaplace.png))</sub>

The OP seeks the first and second moments of $X$, when X has doubly truncated pdf $g(x)$. The first moment is $E_g[X]$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/firstmomentdoublytruncatedLaplace.png))</sub>

and the second moment is $E_g[X^2]$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/secondmomentdoublytruncatedLaplace.png))</sub>

where I am using the `Expect` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the calculations.

Comment: Hi @wolfies, I tried to reproduce your codes there. Since I'm not too familiar with Mathematica, I got nowhere. But, I got my own here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HzUK.png).

Answer (score 0):

There is a closed form for the cdf, that is just a linear scale on the non-truncated cdf. In particular if $X \sim F_X$,  and $Y$ follows the same distribution but truncated on the interval $[a;b]$, then the cdf for $Y$, $F_Y(\cdot)$ is given by $F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{F_X(b)-F_X(a)} F_X(y)$.

To get, say, the first moment,

$$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf_Y(y) dy = \frac{1}{F_X(b)-F_X(a)} \int_a^b yf_X(y) dy.$$

The problem is in general, that we don't know what happens to the last integral when we restrict it to be on $[a;b]$.

**On the truncated normal distribution**

I was imprecise earlier: Here is the derivation for the truncated normal: 
[image: http://imgur.com/ivDGw6L]

As you can see, the crucial step is that the derivative of the normal density is equal to minus the inside times the normal density. In this sense, there is a type of linear invariance of the normal density and without it, this derivation would not work out to be a simple form.

Comment: do you still have the reference? Or, could you give the title of the reference? Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I don't see the connection between the "inherent linearity" (whatever that is) and the moments of a truncated distribution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my lack of clarity. I have elaborated.